# Terraform VPN - Tunnel options

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to set VPN tunnel options through terraform:

```
resource "aws_vpn_connection" "example" {
  customer_gateway_id = "${aws_customer_gateway.example.id}"
  transit_gateway_id  = "${aws_ec2_transit_gateway.example.id}"
  type                = "${aws_customer_gateway.example.type}"
}
```

I don't see any way to set default options within Terraform. Is there a way to get this done using the null resource? Or any other way of setting this up within Terraform?

Comment: did you read this [a document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/vpn_connection.html) ?

Comment: @GNOKOHEAT I did there is no option suggested for setting up default options.